# How do I use an npm package in cypress tests without adding to main project?

Tags: angular, npm, cypress

I have an Angular project with Cypress tests. I'd like to use crypto-js in my Cypress tests but crypto-js is not required in the main project.  How can I 'install' crypto-js for use by Cypress without actually adding crypto-js to package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the package for development only, but do not want it in your build, you can install crypto.js using the following command:

```
npm install crypto-js --save-dev
```